# How do I use ng-repeat to list data from two locations in firebase?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I am using ng-repeat to display a list of posts, I would like to display a picture of the author for each post. My Firebase data structure is divided into users and posts with each user's picture stored under users. What is the best way to access the profile picture for each post?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier to answer if you include a snippet of the relevant JSON (as text, no screenshot please) and the code in your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
 <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="filteredData in posts">
        <td>{{filteredData.post}}</td>
        <td>{{filteredData.pic}}</td>                                  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store pics with the name of author or may be a short code that represent the author with your posts. Now you can use the same way as you are accessing author name to access pics as given in code below. However it would have more useful if you could show your approach here.

```
 <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="postDetail in posts">
        <td>{{postDetail.post}}</td>
        <td><img ng-src = image/{{postDetail.Pic}}.png></td>                                  
    </tr>
</table>
```

You may refer this [Jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RkykR/2133/)